# Share informations between two applications

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I need to share some information between two apps in Android. Specifically, one of the apps can read some information saved by the other app at any time.
Previously it could be done with sharedPreferences and Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE, now deprecated.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That depends a *lot* on the nature of the information and how it needs to be shared (push versus pull). Any of the standard Android IPC mechanisms (service, content provider, broadcast receiver, even activities) can be used to share information between two apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is always a pull action. What do you advise? do you have any examples?

Comment: A content provider is a reasonable approach. Depending on your use case, you could go with its database-style API (make a query, get a `Cursor`) or its streaming-style API (open an `InputStream` or `OutputStream`). For the latter, if the content is backed by a file, you could use `FileProvider` for an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: If it's a small amount of data an Intent with extra could also be used.